# react native button does not fit on the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 7 buttons on the screen, but 1 button is half visible, one button does not fit at all.
my code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

        <Header />

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>
            LC Teknoloji
        </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.Isgr}
            title="İş Giriş"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.Yapilicak}
            title="Yapılacaklar"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.gcms}
            title="İş Geçmişi"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.alnck}
            title="Alınıcaklar"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.ulist}
            title="Ürün Listesi"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.Stok}
            title="Stoklar"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.btnstyl}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.Musteri}
            title="Müşteriler"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

      </ScrollView>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    flex: 1,

    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",



  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 0,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    top: 45,
  },
  btnstyl: {
    left: 120,
    height: 60,
    width: 160,
    marginBottom: -20,
    top: 55,
  },
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2LKt.jpg)

I changed the background color or something, when I pull it up, the buttons come up, it doesn't fit on the screen from the place in the picture

Why do you think the screenshot doesn't fit?

Comment: You should increase the size of the parent component or decrease the height of buttons in your btnstyl class for (example from 60 to 55).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your styles. Remove the  **marginBottom** and **top**

```
const styles = {
.....
btnstyl: {
    left: 120,
    height: 60,
    width: 160
  },
}
```

And add height to the View component of the text above the buttons:

```
<View style={{ height: 100 }}>
  <Text style={styles.headerText}>
   LC Teknoloji
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me what was my logic mistake there for me not to do it again :)